# How to sort a list containing namedtuples based on the difference between attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Segment = namedtuple('Segment', 'start end')
segments = [Segment(start=9, end=1), Segment(start=1, end=3), Segment(start=2, end=5), Segment(start=3, end=6)]
```

I tried the following code to sort the list:

```
sorted(segments, key = lambda s: s.end - s.start)
```

But this doesn't work. How can I do this?

Expected output:

```
[Segment(start=3, end=6), Segment(start=2, end=5), Segment(start=1, end=3), Segment(start=9, end=1)]
```

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: segments = [Segment(start=3, end=6), Segment(start=2, end=5), Segment(start=1, end=3), Segment(start=9, end=1)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that you want the "sequence" where `end < start` or `end - start < 0` first, also in case there are many `segments` that match that criteria, priority should be given to "sequence" with highest `end` value.

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Segment = namedtuple('Segment', 'start end')
>>> segments = [Segment(start=9, end=1), Segment(start=1, end=3), Segment(start=2, end=5), Segment(start=3, end=6)]
>>> sorted(segments, key=lambda s: (s.end < s.start, -s.end))
[Segment(start=3, end=6), Segment(start=2, end=5), Segment(start=1, end=3), Segment(start=9, end=1)]
```